# Is this sentence "I barraged him with an interview" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

"I barraged him with an interview."

The above sentence sounds wrong to me.

I feel like you should barrage someone with either a plural (such as "I barraged him with questions.") or one of those terms that is technically singular but actually represents a multiple things, for example "I barraged him with a bunch of questions".

But given that "a bunch" is technically singular, doesn't that mean my original sentence "I barraged him with an interview," is technically grammatically correct?

Comment: This is very close to being a duplicate; your third paragraph has in essence appeared on ELU before. But you are saying that 'one of those terms that is technically [formally] singular but actually represents a [sic] multiple things' taking plural agreement licenses any singular noun doing so, which is not the case. A few people might argue that 'interview' 'actually represents ... multiple things [= a stream of questions]' by implication, but this reasoning doesn't sound acceptable to me.

Comment: It is grammatically correct but nonsense.

Comment: It is grammatically impeccable yet nonsensical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionary.com defines *barrage* (noun) as

> an overwhelming quantity or explosion, as of words, blows, or criticisms

and defines *barrage* (verb) as

> to subject to a barrage

To *barrage someone with an interview* is probably grammatically correct in the sense given above, but idiomatically it's pretty clunky.

I'd suggest *I subjected him to a barrage of questions during the interview* which would convey all the ideas you're trying to get across.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, "a bunch of" is a determiner for "questions." You're not asking "a bunch," you're asking questions, of which there are a bunch.

You are correct that you should barrage with a plural.